# Interact with standard input/output of another process

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an executable `example.exe`. This executable's behaviour is as follows:

```
1.Waits for input from user
2.Performs some operations, based on input
3.goto 1
```

How can I use `subprocess` or a similar module to interact with executable?

I wish to run the process, insert input, receive output, then insert additional inputs based on the output received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen([r'path/to/process', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

to_program = "something to send to the program's stdin"
while process.poll() == None:  # While not terminated
    process.stdin.write(to_program)

    from_program = process.stdout.readline()  # Modify as needed to read custom amount of output
    if from_program == "something":  # send something new based on stdout
       to_program = "new thing to send to program"
    else:
       to_program = "other new thing to send to program"

print("Process exited with code {}".format(process.poll()))
```

Comment: After first call stdout, stderr = process.communicate(to_program) process terminates... (all additional inputs concidered to be empty string)

Comment: The communicate() method reads all of the output and waits for child process to exit before returning.

Comment: Sorry, should have tested more thoroughly. Try the new example.

Comment: 1- in general, you don't know how much should you read and [there are other issues with the interactive `subprocess` usage](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe) 2- there is no need to call `process.poll()` here and it is not enough to call `process.poll()` -- the process may exit after `.poll()` call but before the `.write()` call (unrelated: use `is None` instead of `== None`). You should handle `IOError` errors (`EPIPE`, `EINVAL`) raised by `.write()` instead. If `from_program` is empty then it means EOF and you could exit the loop.

Comment: 3- minor: close the pipes and call `process.wait()` at the end.