# How to interact with terminal using python

Tags: python, command-line, cmd, terminal, yowsup

this is a command line program which I can use via terminal using the following commands

```
yowsup-cli demos --yowsup --config config.txt
```

after running this command I always got this info:

> yowsup-cli  v2.0.15 yowsup      v2.5.0
>
> Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Tarek Galal http://www.openwhatsapp.org
>
> This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution
>   is encouraged.
>
> If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
>   development please consider donating:
>   http://openwhatsapp.org/yowsup/donate
>
> Yowsup Cli client
>   ================== Type /help for available commands
>
> [offline]:

And the indicator prompts me to insert "**/L**" to continue .

My question is how to send the command to terminal and get the response and then send another command based on the response "**/L in this case**" using python code so I can interact with terminal via python exactly as I can do with terminal emulator my self

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interact with standard input/output of another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060281/interact-with-standard-input-output-of-another-process)

Comment: I found this answer, which looks very similar to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python

Comment: @gre_gor thank you for your answer but it doesn't work with my problem

Comment: @chleboir thank you for your answer but it doesn't work with my problem also